# Unhandled exception java.net.MalformedURLException in an Android app

Tags: java, parsing, url, exception

I have a problem in my code

```
void getItembyID(String code){
    String site;
    site = "http:/www.sprii.net/db/getItem.php?pid="+code+"/";
    URL url = new URL(site);
}
```

I get an exception in the third line while writing in IntelliJ. The problem is with `URL url = new URL(site);` Should I just try/catch it? Why does it happen? I tried inputting `"http://www.google.com/"` to see if it works with that and it still gives me the same exception

EDIT: I realised I have an error in my site name. It misses // after http:. However, after changing that I still get "java.net.MalformedURLException"

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: You didn't get an exception. You get a *compiler error message* which is *about* the exception that you aren't handling. Then when you fixed that with a `try/catch` block, you got the exception, due to a - guess what - malformed URL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are missing a /

Try using "http://www.sprii.net/db/getItem.php?pid="

Perhaps you should expand this function so you can see more errors if they occur, like the code below. (By the way, this executes for me, but I don't know any valid "code" value for the argument)

```
    public void getItembyID(String code) {
    String site;

    site = "http://www.sprii.net/db/getItem.php?pid=" + code + "/";

    try {
        URL url = new URL(site);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: I did have that wrong! But changing it doesn't seem to fix the problem

Comment: Try dropping the end slash? I don't know if that's an issue but it's worth a try

Comment: End slash didn't help

Answer (score 2):

I realised what the problem was.
This error means that the method I'm calling is declared with `throws` and because of that has to be handled with `try{}catch(){}` or by adding an identical `throws`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `String code` does not have any spaces, if you should encode it before appending

I got a similar error when I sent the below URL

> String unEncodedUrl =
>   "https://yXXXXXXdh.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/helloWorld?date=29
>   Dec 2017";
>
> URL url = new URL(unEncodedUrl);

the above line has thrown error because there are **spaces in the date url query value**

so you can solve it by encoding the date value

> String encodedUrl =
>   "https://yXXXXXXdh.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/helloWorld?date="+URLEncoder.encode(finaldate,"utf-8");

**note:** do not encode the entire URL only encode the part which contains spaces

Answer (score -3):

You are missing a / in the url.
Should be http://